# How to substitute content from a Div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change manually the content of a div using jQuery, depending on the image I click. Each image has it's own description, so when I click on it, what I want to do is to change the content of a div like this:

```
var url_image = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
$(document).find('#descripcion').append($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
$(document).find('#containerImage')
    .css('background-image', 'url(' + url_image + ')')
```

So with this code I change the background-image of the div `#containerImage`, and also the description shown on the div `#descripcion`. The problem is obvious: as I'm using *append( bla bla )*, every time I click on each image I append it's description, and so on, with no erasing the previous ones.

I suppose there should be a method, not append, not prepend, that erases the content and substitutes it, but it has been several hours searching for that and I can't find how.

So please, if you could help me with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$("#descripcion").html($(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
```

It will change the text inside `#descripcion` block.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.html()`, and don't do `$(document).find()`

```
var $img = $(this).find('img');
$('#descripcion').html($img.attr('alt'));
$('#containerImage').css('background-image', 'url(' + $img.attr('src') + ')');
```

Comment: +1, this cache of the found image is good, using the id for each element should be fastest (no "document") and is also good.  Not sure why the OP originally spells it "descripcion" for the description :) but you caught that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Maybe OP is Spanish-speaking.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I assumed it was a language I didn't know and left it alone :P

Comment: @VisioN - perhaps, :) sometimes I am too localized in my brain funk.